# Multiprocessing/Threading with python causes segmentation fault after half the files are processed

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a programm which needs to process files of different length (200 MB -> 1.5 GB) and would like to speed up the process by using multiprocessing/multithreading. 
This works really well until some point when the whole process slows down and it appears that only one or two processes are still runnning.
I looked at possible reasons. Increasing the heap stack didn't help.
The processes are using numpy to quite a large extent, so I figured it might have something to do with CPython. But no luck looking for answers.

Here's the code:

```
startPD,endPD,startHC,endHC = 0,10,0,10

threadlistPD = []
threadlistHC = []

procs = []

for i in range(5):

    if i <= 4:

        no = i + 1
        filelistPDtemp = filelistPD[startPD:endPD]
        namelistPDtemp = namelistPD[startPD:endPD]

        namePD = "Test Group "+str(i)
        procPD = Process(target=analyseFolder, name=namePD, args=(pathPD, filelistPDtemp, namelistPDtemp, True))
        procs.append(procPD)
        procPD.start()

        startPD += 10
        endPD += 10
    if i <= 3:

        no = i +5
        filelistHCtemp = filelistHC[startHC:endHC]
        namelistHCTemp = namelistHC[startHC:endHC]
        nameHC = "Control Group "+str(i)
        procHC = Process(target=analyseFolder, name=nameHC, args=(pathHC, filelistHCtemp, namelistHCTemp, True))
        procs.append(procHC)
        procHC.start()

        endHC += 10
        startHC +=10
    if i == 4:
        no = i + 5
        nameHC = "Control Group "+str(i)
        procHC = Process(target=analyseFolder, name=nameHC, args=(pathHC, filelistHCtemp, namelistHCTemp, True))
        procs.append(procHC)
        procHC.start()

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you maybe creating more processes / threads than you have processors / cores?  Besides overloading your CPU, each of these will consume memory, so if you have too many you might run out of memory which is often not properly handled.  On the C level (e. g. within numpy) a `malloc()` will only return NULL then, and any access on that address will result in a segfault.

Comment: True I have only eight cores available. I'll change that and see if that solves the issue. What confuses me most however is the fact that it becomes slower even before that.

Comment: Well, eight cores might be sufficiently loaded with four processes.  And other things might as well run on the host and need some CPU time (desktops etc.).